# (Mac OS X, XAMPP) + memcache -> no suitable image found

Tags: php, macos, memcached, xampp

I have a issues installing memcache on my MacBook with OS X 10.8. I have installed memcachen. when i run memcache -h it get an answer. But when i call php -m i can't find it. When i execute phpinfo() and check the log afterwards i get the following log entry. Any idea?

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/php-5.3.1/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/memcache.so' - dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/php-5.3.1/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/memcache.so, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:\n\t/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/php-5.3.1/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/memcache.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture in Unknown on line 0

Thanks for your help

Comment: Well, the error states that the library you try to load has the wrong architecture. Maybe another type of cpu it is compiled for or the difference between 32 and 64 bit?

Comment: Thanks, what did i wrong? I downloaded xampp + devl tools. Then i executed: 
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
sudo make install
And afterwards i called "/pecl install memcache"

Comment: I have no idea about MacOS, sorry, using Linux. You have to compile that stuff first? I thought Mac is that user friendly... Anyways, you write you specified `--prefix=/usr/local`, yet the path starts with `/Applications/XAMPP/...`... I'd say you are dealing with two different files. Maybe a previous installation attempt?

Comment: did you find an answer to this question by any chance?? I've having the exact problem!

Answer (score 0):

Your xampp is 64Bit Software and memcache.so is 32 bit or vice versa! In any case this Version of memcache.so does simply not match to the xampp you do use. Xampp offers elder version in 32bit and newer ones in 64. You might try that or find a different Version of the lib.

If Sourcecode is available you might compile the lib on your system, this will help too.